# Upgrading to 4.6 Joomla. Civi Mail can't generate the text editor

Tags: civimail, upgrade, 4.6.2

Since I upgraded to 4.6  I can't create any Newsletter email anymore. Html Editor is not showing. Please see two images step 1 and step 2 to understand process.

[image: Calling new email]

[image: page that comes up after calling a new email]

Comment: also the civi menu bar looks really wired after pressing new email.

Comment: can you add a screenshot?

Comment: This question contains no details and does not evidence any research effort on your part. Have you googled to find the hundred or so similar problems and tried any of those solutions? Have you gone through the [javascript troubleshooting steps](http://forum.civicrm.org/index.php/topic,35850)?

Comment: Added two screenshots now.

Comment: Hi I went through the troubleshootingsteps. Unfortunately there was not error listed.